# Issue clearing cookies in deployed Node.js application

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, deployment

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue with clearing cookies in my deployed Node.js application. I have tried various approaches, but none of them seem to work. The application is deployed on Vercel at:
Backend:https://naimu-app-nodejs.vercel.app
Frontend: https://naimu-app.vercel.app

Here's what I have tried so far:

user.js

```
// =============================== logout user ===============================
router.get(
  "/logout",
  isAuthenticatedUser,
  catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      res.cookie("token", "", {
        expires: new Date(0),
        domain: "naimu-app.vercel.app",
        path: "/",
        sameSite: "none",
      });

      // localhost
      // res.cookie("token", null, {
      //   expires: new Date(Date.now()),
      //   httpOnly: true,
      //   sameSite: "none",
      //   secure: true,
      // });

      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Logged out.",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
    }
  })
);
```

How I created the token to login: (Works including after deployment)
jwtToken.js

```
// create token and save in cookies
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = user.getJwtToken();

  // options for cookie
  const options = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // 90 days
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
  };

  res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
    success: true,
    user,
    token,
  });
};

module.exports = sendToken;
```

I have also verified that the cookie name, domain, and path are correct for my deployment. However, the cookies are not being cleared successfully.

I suspect there might be some specific considerations or configurations related to the hosting provider or deployment environment that I'm missing.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly clear cookies in a deployed Node.js application? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!